# Create an in-cell drop-down (Google Sheet Data Validation) from a CSV list with Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a spreadsheet that has multiple editors. I get a list of all users separated by comma using:

```
var users = ss.getEditors().toString();
```

Rather than having a list of users separated by comma, which looks ugly (I have 100+ users), I would like to set up a drop down menu to view users. To do that, I have written this:

```
function Dropdown() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var TestSheetName = "Test"
  var TestSheet = ss.getSheetByName(TestSheetName);
  var users = ss.getEditors().toString();
  TestSheet.getRange(1, 1).setDataValidation(SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation()
    .setAllowInvalid(true)
    .requireValueInList([users], true)
    .build()
  );
}
```

The drop down menu created shows the list with commas. What is bizarre is when I right click on the cell and go to "Data Validation," I can see that the users are put in correctly. When I then click 'OK' to close the menu, the dropdown corrects itself and I have the list of users correctly formatted.

Am I doing something wrong with my code? Or is this a bug?

Appreciate your insights.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expected input format for [`requireValueInList`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/data-validation-builder#requireValueInList(String)) is an array of `String`s. As you mention, `ss.getEditors().toString()` creates a `String` of comma-separated emails. You then wrap this **single** `String` object into an array, and pass it to the data validation builder. Effectively, this is akin to:

```
.requireValueInList(["email@example.com,email2@example.org"])
```

which is decidedly different than

```
.requireValueInList(["email@example.com", "email2@example.org"])
```

The solution is to not call `.toString()` on the array of `User` objects that is returned by [`ss.getEditors()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getEditors()). Instead, convert the [`User[]`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/user) to `String[]` by calling its method `getEmail()` on each user, and then pass this array of `String`s to the Data Validation builder:

```
var emails = ss.getEditors().map(function (user) { return user.getEmail(); });
/*...*/
.requireValueInList(emails, true)
/*...*/
```

should be sufficient.

When you manually open the Data Validation UI, it splits the input single string as many different strings, which is why when you click OK, the drop-down populates as you originally intended.